# Couldn't find "liballjoyn_java.so"

Tags: java, android, alljoyn

I'm working on an android chat room with alljoyn service. In the libs folder I have created the folder armeabi and added the liballjoyn_java.so file there.
I have added the dependencies necessary but I keep getting this error:

Couldn't find "liballjoyn_java.so"

when I try to load the library:

```
static {
    Log.i(TAG, "System.loadLibrary(\"alljoyn_java\")");
    System.loadLibrary("alljoyn_java");
 }
```

I don't know where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your java-library-path is unable to locate the alljoyn_java folder.

try using

```
System.load(absolute path to the alljoyn_java folder)
```

alljoyn_java folder must be in the

`core->alljoyn folder`